# Run Flask app in Pycharm community Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, flask, windows-10, pycharm

How to set up a Run configuration for flask App in Pycharm Community on Windows?
I found **Flask.exe** for Flask after installing on venv/Script but yet there should be a way to execute it using a Flask Python script to make it work with the default Python Run configuration.

[image: Pycharm Run configuration]

Answer (score 2):

Make a file `app.py`and add the code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Then open a cmd in the `app.py` folder and run in console `flask run` or start it from PyCharm 
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czRLw.png)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your Python file where the Flask app is defined:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And setup your configuration to run that script.

You can read more about this method of running flask app [in the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/server/#in-code).  Remember that it is not a suitable way to run Flask apps in production (and neither is flask.exe).